# Align children in Tikz tree

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees

I try to align the children in a tree in a way, such that the tree will fit on the page without overlapping.

I have made my own Fault Tree out of this [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fault-tree/), nothing too special. The important part of the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm,
    text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-1.05cm)
        -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm,level distance=1.4cm,
        growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
    ]
    \node (g1) [event] {Het klimaatsysteem levert geen goede luchtkwaliteit}
        child {node (g2) {Geen lucht}
            child {node (g4){Falen ventilator}}
            child {node (g5){Lek luchtkanalen}}
            child {node (g6){Lek kleppen}}
        }
        child[level distance=3cm] {node (g3) {Slechte kwaliteit}
            child[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4cm] {node (g7){Vuile lucht}
                child {node (g10){Vuil filter}}
                child {node (g11){Verstopte buitenroosters}}
            }
            child[level distance=1.5cm] {node (g8){Verkeerde luchtvochtigheid}
                child {node (g12){Erosie druppelvanger}}
                child {node (g13){Te weinig bevochtiging}}
            }
            child[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4cm] {node (g9){Verkeerde temperatuur}
                child {node (g14){Lekkende verwarming}}
                child {node (g15){Lekkende koelbatterij}}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code displayed above results in the tree in the next picure(without the colored shapes):[image]

Now I want the block saying 'Verkeerde temperatuur', on the right, to be straight under the block on the previous level, like the level with 'Verkeerde temperatuur' is aligned to the left.

I hope I was clear and that anybody can come up with a solution. Thanks in advance.

PS. don't mind the overlapping and other small errors in the picture

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see **compilable code**, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place option `grow=down` on this child it will be placed immediately below the node above.  You will then need to shift the other two children to the left with e.g. `xshift=5cm`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    and/.style={and gate US,thick,draw,fill=red!60,rotate=90,
                anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    or/.style={or gate US,thick,draw,fill=blue!60,rotate=90,
                anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    be/.style={circle,thick,draw,fill=green!60,anchor=north,
                minimum width=0.7cm},
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,fill=purple!60,rotate=90,
                anchor=east,minimum width=0.8cm},
    label distance=3mm,
    every label/.style={blue},
event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm,
                text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-1.05cm)
        -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm,level distance=1.4cm,
        growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
]
\node (g1) [event] {Het klimaatsysteem levert geen goede luchtkwaliteit}
        child {node (g2) {Geen lucht}
            child {node (g4){Falen ventilator}}
            child {node (g5){Lek luchtkanalen}}
            child {node (g6){Lek kleppen}}
        }
        child[level distance=3cm] {node (g3) {Slechte kwaliteit}
            child[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4cm, xshift=-6cm] {node (g7){Vuile lucht}
                child {node (g10){Vuil filter}}
                child {node (g11){Verstopte buitenroosters}}
            }
            child[level distance=1.5cm, xshift=-5cm] {node[text width=2.5cm] (g8){Verkeerde luchtvochtigheid}
                child {node (g12){Erosie druppelvanger}}
                child {node (g13){Te weinig bevochtiging}}
            }
            child[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4cm,grow=down] {node (g9){Verkeerde temperatuur}
                child {node (g14){Lekkende verwarming}}
                child {node (g15){Lekkende koelbatterij}}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```